# PHP sprintf not working with french variables.

Tags: php

I have a website which works in 2 languages(English & French).
I am using the sprintf function to generate dynamic data. 
But it is not working in french version.

Sample Code:

```
$boulevardières = "Partez à l'aventure aux commandes des %s. Consultez tous les détails ou comparez les modèles de all %s %s."
$category_name= "bike";
echo $output= sprintf($boulevardières,$categoryName,$categoryName,2018);
```

I guess it is the variable name [$boulevardières] that is causing this problem. 
As in my code variable names are generated dynamically I cannot keep anything static which does not have the French accent.

Any suggestions how I can make this work?

Comment: What's not working? Your code [works fine](https://3v4l.org/9WD5K), just had some typos.

Comment: *"Any suggestions how I can make this work?"* -- you can start by noticing that `$category_name` is not the same thing as `$categoryName`. Also, the missing semicolon (`;`) after the assignment to `$boulevardières` doesn't allow the script to be executed.

Comment: I was in a hurry so I typed wrong variables names here. In my code I am pulling the data from the text files, and its not working

Comment: I am also in a hurry. Moving on.

Comment: I think you need the characters formatted in ISO-8859-1. Maybe consider some other method for generating the variable names maybe you can try something like htmlentities(utf8_decode($varName)); before the variable name is assigned.

Comment: which IDE are you using ? check if encoding file in ANSI

Comment: Why are you generating variables dynamically? Anything that does that should probably be using associative arrays instead.

Comment: @digital-pollution - I can't keep Boulevardi?res (utf-decoded value) instead of Boulevardières, but still I can figure it out now how to make it work. Thanks :)

Comment: @Barmar - I have a list of categories which I am fetching through the foreach loop. Name of the category is taken as the variable name and that variable name is compared with the text file.

Comment: @GaneshKandu - I am using dreamweaver. It is working fine with the descriptions that are written in the french but does not work if i assign the variable name in french

Answer (score 0):

Text file: [filename_fr.txt]

```
boulevardières = "Partez à l'aventure aux commandes des %s. Consultez tous les détails ou comparez les modèles de all %s %s."
```

PHP code:

```
$file=(boulevardières ,filename_fr);
$categoryName = "bike";
echo $pg_landing = sprintf($file,$categoryName,$categoryName,$year);
```

The code works fine with the English versions but not with the French.